# Finding an object's location/scale with values set to zero?

Tags: mesh, objects, dimensions, conversion

Is there a way to find the exact location, rotation, and scale of an object that has these values set to zero, possibly through `clear object transformations`?

I would like to set an object that's originally made for a child rig (location, scale), to the values of this adult female rig.

[image: Adult Female hairstyle location, scale, etc]

Unfortunately, the only values that are still there are the dimensions. This Blender file was extracted by a program that makes smaller and specific files from FullBuild.package game files.

[image: Location,scale of child version hairstyle]

This is also the case with the Blender file of the object I'm trying to convert to the adult female rig. Values are also set to zero.
I tried copying the dimensions of the adult female hairstyle to the (target) child hairstyle just to see what happens but that makes the mesh twice as big.

I've searched a lot here and elsewhere but did not find any info on 'unsetting' clear object transformations which probably means it's not possible. I just want to make sure this the case.

Is there another way to copy the scale, location to an object? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the location and rotation values of an object are set to 0, and scale values are set to 1, it means that it has its location, rotation and scale either set to default or applied (scale zero would make it compressed to a single point). As far as I know, there is no way to retrieve the original values (unless undo `apply transformations` immediately, without saving and closing).

There's a possibility to estimate the original location: applying location makes x = y = z = 0 but it means the object's pivot is at (0, 0, 0) - so you can temporarily use "set origin to geometry" to get its actual position, in a sense.

Here an example starting situation:

[image]

After using the command `set origin to geometry`:

[image]

You get its current position, e.g. Y-translated, in the example.

To get rotation and scale after applying them is impossible, as far as I know, unless you have a reference object, but that should have been planned in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I tried the commands you suggested but now the mesh start to float high above the head of the rig. I think it's going to get to game specific from this point on then. Hopefully These values can be located by the developers of the program that I use to excract the blender files from the fullbuild files.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you properly, how how you get those objects into blender (format, importer, settings, etc) from what you start and what you need to get... maybe it's me, sorry.